# Convert JSON with illegal characters in property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Beforehand; I'm using an old version of Newtonsoft.Json (4.0.8.0).

So I'm trying to write a .NET client for a webserver application.
To convert all incoming packets from a json structure to .NET object i do use the JSON Serializer with the inbuilt function JToken.ToObject.
This requires the target .net class to have the needed attributes named exactly as the incoming json data ones.

Now I came across a data packet which contains invalid property names in the scope of C# (.NET overall I think).
It looks like this.

```
"12345" : {
  "Name1/Part2": {}
  "Name2/Part2": {}
  "Name3/Part2": {}
  "Name4/Part2": {}
  "Name5/Part2": {}
}
```

the equal .net code would be.

```
class DataPacket {
  public DummyObject 12345 {get; set;}


  public class DummyObject {
    public object Name1/Part2 {get; set}
    public object Name2/Part2 {get; set}
    public object Name3/Part2 {get; set}
    public object Name4/Part2 {get; set}
    public object Name5/Part2 {get; set}
  }
}
```

where as all property names are illegal ('starting with number', 'illegal characters -> /').

Any idea how I can solve this problem with the Major 4 Version of Newtonsoft?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the jsonproperty attribute so for the first one something like:

```
class DataPacket{
                    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="1234")]
                    public DummyObject OneTwoThreeFour {get;set;}//or whatever you want to name.
                }
```

do that for each json property you need to convert that has illegal names

Comment: I think it's `JsonProperty` not `JSONProperty`

Comment: If each property has an unique name, this would result in a lot of `dummy` objects